# Can i join ground and signal wire in antenna?

Tags: antenna, antenna-array

Is there need to connect ground and signal wire differently in yagi antenna. I took outer shield(ground) and inner part(signal) of coax cable  ( coming from antenna) and twisted them together and then connected the same way to wifi receiver  . Will it work ?? Is there any need to change in it?

Comment: The shield and center conductor of the co-ax MUST be connected to two different points on the antenna.

Comment: Um, why do you think the thing *has* a separation between inner and outer conductor? Even without understanding the electrodynamics behind that, *twisting something together that someone else put a lot of effort into separating* should have appeared *unwise* to you.

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work at all.

You're shorting the signal to ground. The device won't receive anything with a cable that's wired that way.

Comment: But i tried its working but heating?? Is it ue to that??

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that a standard Yagi has a balanced output, in the absense of a balun it would work poorly anyway.

> I took outer shield(ground) and inner part(signal) of coax cable (
>   coming from antenna) and twisted them together and then connected the
>   same way to wifi receiver . Will it work ??

If you shorted a microphone out and connected it to your amplifier would you hear anything through the speakers? No.

However, given that you may have not used a balun and shorted stuff out in a way that might form some kind of resonant stub AND, given that radio waves can find their way into inputs of sensitive RF amplifiers in perculiar ways AND if enough signal is present to get some half decent demodulation then all sorts of things are possible (and might seem possible to to the noob).